# How to use "hugo new" command

Tags: multilingual, hugo

I'm using Hugo (v0.58.1) in a multilingual environment. My posts are stored in different folders. For example:

- `content/en/…`
- `content/fr/…`

I can't figure out hot to use `hugo new --kind post` command to create an `.md` file by language/folder (ex. `hugo new --kind post fr/2019/09/…`)?

Maybe `-c`, `--contentDir` string or `-d`, `--destination` string flags? But I don't understand how to use them.

```
hugo new -k post -c /Users/ns/projects/hugo/tests/hugo-template/content/fr/post/2019/09/07/test.md
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [translation by content directory mode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/#translation-by-content-directory) so you need to pass the `-c` or `--contentDir` parameter:

```
hugo new -c content/fr post/2019/09/07/test.md
```

Comment: I've already tried -c and -d flags as suggested but it creates the file at "content/en" and not at "content/fr"

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `config.toml` to suppress “en”:

```
disableLanguages = ["en"]
```

And try again:

```
hugo new post/helloworld.md
```

Answer (score 0):

faced the same problem as you, I've managed to create the post using this command.

```bash
hugo new ../fr/YYYY/MM/DD/file-name.md
```

as you can see I've used ".." to go back in directory, and it worked for me.